# typedef decltype function pointer not returning proper output (cout)

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem using decltype to create a typedef function pointer to "foo". printf works but with a warning: `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘bar {aka int (*)(int)}’ [-Wformat=]` and cout displays "1". I'm sort of a newbie when it comes to function pointers so I don't really know what's going on. Can someone help me here?

```
#include <iostream>
int foo(int a) {
    return a;
}
int main() {
    typedef decltype(&foo) bar;
    printf("printf: %d\n", (*bar(70))); //work with a warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘bar {aka int (*)(int)}’ [-Wformat=]
    std::cout << "cout: " << (*bar(80));//displays "cout: 1" for some reason
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bar` is not a function pointer, it's a type, and `bar(70)` is a function-style type cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create variable of type `bar` and initialize it with `foo` address.

because `()` has higher precedence than `*`, you have to use parentheses `(*var)(80)` to dereference pointer to function, after that you can call it:

```
typedef decltype(&foo) bar;
bar b = &foo;
printf("printf: %d\n", ((*b)(70))); //work with a warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘bar {aka int (*)(int)}’ [-Wformat=]
std::cout << "cout: " << ((*b)(80));//displays "cout: 1" for some reason
```

or just:

```
b(80)
```

without explicit dereferencing.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jXa3sC)